# cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead ? in VS 2005

Tags: ado.net, visual-studio-2005, c++-cli

I am using a C++ language I am getting a strange error when I am try to create a simple object of DataTable its giving error

System::Data::DataTable* myDataTable = new DataTable();

even I tried this
 System::Data::DataTable myDataTable = new DataTable();
getting the following error please help.

error C2750: 'System::Data::DataTable' : cannot use 'new' on the reference type; use 'gcnew' instead
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'System::Data::DataTable *' to 'System::Data::DataTable ^

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The language you are using is called [C++/CLI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/CLI), not plain C++. In [C++/CLI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163681.aspx), you can access .NET stuff like `DataTable`. The semantics are a bit different from raw pointers:

```
DataTable^ myDataTable = gcnew DataTable;
```

"`^`" denotes a [managed handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xey702bw.aspx). Under the hood, it's a pointer to an object on the GC heap. You can't do pointer arithmetic on managed handles. You don't `delete` them manually. The GC will take care of them. It's also free to move the objects around unless they are pinned explicitly. [`gcnew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/te3ecsc8(VS.80).aspx) is used to allocate objects on the managed heap. It returns a handle, not a raw pointer. You can't create .NET reference types on unmanaged C++ heap using `new`.

Comment: Impressive Mehrdad, It solved my problem. Thanks very much :)